# When to water a garden based on soil moisture monitoring?

Tags: watering

I have a network of soil moisture monitors set up in my flower garden.  I've been collecting data for about a month now, and don't quite know how to interpret the information I have.

All of the flowers and plants seem to be green and healthy - that's the most important thing.

I am trying to figure out how to relate the moisture data to when to give the plants some water.

I have not watered the garden at all in the last month - I don't think it has been necessary, and the green and blossoming flowers seem to say I'm right.

The garden is a rectangle about 5 meters by 11 meters (15 by 35 feet) and is covered about 10 centimeters (4 inches) deep with bark. The bark keeps the soil (mostly) from drying out.

I have some information that says that, for example, roses need between 17 and 60 percent soil moisture.  That's useful, but not enough.

Here's the soil moisture chart for one monitor for the last couple of days:

[image]

The moisture dips drastically from about noon until mid-afternoon.  The dips are below what my information says is adequate - but the information I have doesn't mention whether to go by the daily average or the lowest level during the day.  The dips have been getting wider and deeper the last few days.

This is the soil moisture distribution in the garden at about noon time today:

[image]

Red shading to black is under 20 percent.

**Do plants need a soil moisture level that is always above some limit, or should I look at the daily averages to decide when it's too dry?**

---

The soil moisture monitoring is a sort of experiment I'm carrying out.  I'm trying to see how the soil moisture changes with the time of day and the temperature. I'm also trying to gather enough information to make use of what the sensors tell me.

Right now I'm mostly just collecting loads of data and trying to make sense of it.

---

Further information for alephzero:

Plots made last year using data from the manufacturer's software:

[image]

The moisture drops as much or more on the red day (2020-05-26) as on the purple day (2020-05-20) despite the purple day being hotter.

This is a plot from a sensor in a part of the garden that stays moister than the average:

[image]

That starts at the end of March.  The last few days of March show the daily "dips" around noon time.  We got a little rain on 1 April, and since then the moisture in that part of the garden has stayed above about 60 percent.  We got more rain around 12-13 April, causing the moisture to rise a bit.  Note that the last few days have had small "dips" of a few percent around noon time.

I don't know what is going on.  I do know that there's no error in the data transmission (the "dips" show up when using my software and when using the manufacturer's software) and that the sensors work properly even when it is hot because the other values from the sensors (temperature, light, soil conductivity) continue delivering reasonable values.  As well, the soil moisture doesn't show dips on hot days - **if** it rained the day before.

The only conclusion I can draw is that the soil moisture changes drastically around noon time because the water is evaporating faster than it can be transported from deeper down.

---

A larger portion of the garden dropped below 20 percent today:

[image]

Comment: IMO you have got a problem with the measurement system. Either the sensor doesn't work properly at the hottest time of day, or you have a cable connection that doesn't like high temperatures, or there is a bug in the data logging software. The moisture level "instantly" dropping that much and then "instantly" recovering to the previous level doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @alephzero: No cables, it is all Bluetooth and WIFI.  The soil moisture has those mid-day dips consistently when it is warm and it hasn't rained.  On days after it rains, there's no dip.  After that, the dips start appearing and gradually get deeper and wider.  They show up in my software, but also when using the original software from the manufacturer.  The blue area (upper left corner) consistently shows more moisture than the rest of the yard, but it gets as warm there as anywhere else.

Comment: "Instantly" isn't quite "instant."  The measurements are taken once an hour, so there's time between each measurement for things to change.

Comment: If you can provide an explanation why the soil moisture changes suddenly in one 30-minute period, then stabilizes, then suddenly changes back in another 30 minute period, please tell us what the cause is. I still think either the sensors or the communication link is the issue. For example, from the OP's graph, it could be a problem where any reading ***higher*** than 36% is being corrupted and recorded as too low..

Comment: One test you could try: make the measurement interval shorter (say 1 minute) and run the system on  a day when you expect the problem. I would bet you will still get the same big jumps from one data point to the next.

Comment: @alephzero:  I've added more plots that make it clear that the sensors and the data gathering are correctly reporting what is going on, and that neither the sensors nor the software are totally screwed up.

Comment: I've never trusted moisture readers. Soil resistance depends on soil composition, soil ions, temperature, as well as water content. In a single plot they may work for you, but treating all plots the same is looking for trouble. Lots of different methods are used to make these meters: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soil_moisture_sensor I still picking up a handful of dirt and feeling it.

Comment: @WayfaringStranger:  The moisture sensors are capacitive sensors.  The gadgets I'm using are multifunction.  Besides the capacitive moisture measurement, they also have a conductivity measurement (resistance) as well as temperature and light.